# htaccess redirect of 404 error just prints filename, doesn't execute file

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

On an Apache host, I have a folder called **/thumbs** with a program in it called **program.php** that I will use to create thumbnails.

There is a .htaccess file that contains the following lines:

```
options -indexes
errordocument 404 program.php
```

What **should happen** is that when I call /thumbs/image1.jpg, program.php should be executed.

What **actually happens** is that the browser just **echoes the name of the program**. Calling /thumbs/image1.jpg results in the browser showing:

```
program.php
```

and no code is executed.

I have used this technique on many other sites and it has worked, but not this time.

Anybody know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ErrorDocument` directive can be used several ways, depending on the syntax.  To execute a file the way you want, you must use the full path relative to the DocumentRoot, preceded with a /.  Otherwise, it's taken to be a literal message to be displayed, which is what is happening for you.

Try this:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /thumbs/program.php
```

More info here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument